# Merging two contacts

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I am looking to merge two contacts together as they are duplicate records. I want to ensure all the tags, groups and contributions all carry over too. I just want to do this on an individual record and not merge an entire group of contacts. i have looked at the 'Find and merge duplicate contacts' tab, however that seem to be only for groups.
Does anyone know how to do this for one person who has two records please?

Thanks,

Grace

Answer (score 5):

To merge 2 contact records, select both contacts from a list then select the action 'Merge contacts' from the 'Actions' drop down.  In the resulting screen you will see there are several options that you can check/uncheck - one of the most useful ones is the option near the top of the screen to 'flip' the 2 contacts - the left hand one is regarded as the duplicate.  Also, the deleted record goes in the trash so if you make a mistake you can always retrieve it.

Comment: Details can be found here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#using-rules-and-merging-duplicate-contacts-manually